# Does the smell of paint linger or penetrate other materials?

Tags: painting

My girlfriend is away for the weekend, I and I want to suprise her by doing some painting and some shelfmaking.

The wall I want to paint is a in a rather small room, with a lot of old screw holes that I'm going to fix and paint over (the whole wall) before mounting the shelf.

The problem is that the room is filled with a lot of cloth and stuff, and the room does not have direct ventilation to fresh air (no window).

Will the smell of paint stick to the clothes?

Comment: If you get a low-VOC (or specifically-labelled "low odour") paint, that will greatly reduce the paint smell. There are other benefits (and challenges) to using low-VOC paints, and lots of differences between "truly zero-VOC" and "meets the labelling requirements to say low-VOC" so you should do some research if you're interested in this route.

Answer (score 3):

No - the smell of new paint fades away over time.  It won't stick to clothes any longer than it emanates from the painted surface.

I hope you're using latex paint and not oil - as the smell fades away much faster.

Comment: Well, id does not say. its thinned/cleaned by water... does that give you a clue?
Its "acrylicpaint" if that says something. But im still good right? It states you can paint after 4 hours, so if i do that I can easy wash with a soft cloth later tomorrow that would help the smell?

Comment: Sounds like latex, and no, washing it won't help the smell.  It will only last a day or two.  Get a small fan and put it in the door to help circulate the air in the room.

Comment: @Jason94 **DO NOT WASH IT TOMORROW!** While latex/acrylic paints dry in a few hours, they do not fully harden for several days or even weeks. Washing too soon risks damage to the surface and may affect longevity.